# sql to linq with left join

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join

i have create a request in SQL and put them in dataset. apparently it hang when the data very huge. so i use an Entity.

my original sql is like this:

```
SELECT NO_ORDRE,ORDRE.CODE_DEST as CODE_DEST,REF_EXPED,ORDRE.MODAL_MODE,RS_NOM,ADRESSE,TEL,VILLE,
ORDRE.NBR_COLIS,ORDRE.POID,DATE_CREE,DATE_CLOTUR,STATUT_ORDRE,ORDRE.TRANSPORTEUR,ORDRE.LIB_TOURNE,
ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL,ORDRE.OBS,AUTRE_REF,
ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT+'_'+CAST(NOID as VARCHAR(50))+'_'+SUBSTRING(NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL, 0, CHARINDEX('_', NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL + '_')) as NOLV
FROM ORDRE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
 ON  charindex('_'+cast(ORDRE.NO_ORDRE as varchar(255))+'_', '_'+LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL+'_') > 0

WHERE DATE_CREE BETWEEN @DATE_CREE_DEB AND @DATE_CREE_FIN
ORDER BY NO_ORDRE DESC
```

and i try my linq like this:

```
public IQueryable<ORDRE> Get_OrdreEntity(DateTime datedeb, DateTime datefin)
        {
            try
            {
                IQueryable<ORDRE> LesListe;
                Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities();              

                var query = from o in oEntite_T.ORDRE
                            where o.DATE_CREE >= datedeb && o.DATE_CREE <= datefin                            
                            select o;

                LesListe = query;

                return LesListe;
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
            }
        }
```

it works well but i don't know how to make a join from this sql:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
 ON  charindex('_'+cast(ORDRE.NO_ORDRE as varchar(255))+'_', '_'+LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL+'_') > 0
```

and how can i translate it to linq from this sql:

```
ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT+'_'+CAST(NOID as VARCHAR(50))+'_'+SUBSTRING(NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL, 0, CHARINDEX('_', NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL + '_')) as NOLV
```

Comment: Maybe if your data is going to be huge you could use a view? It would come with more advantages than using a framework?

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't see any reason to have exception handling in the Get_OrdreEntity function. It should be coded in way it just work. Debug it. In any way you do nothing in catch.
2. I you query and filter data in this function and want to get results it is a good idea to return collection instead of query in the result of this function to eliminate performance and side effect isssues. I.e. return IEnumerable, ICollection, IList wherether you want.
3. It is easy to find a ton of Linq join examples, just use Google. [Here is](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) all you need.